# AbortBroadcast with media button long press

Tags: android, android-broadcast

How can I abort voice dialer broadcast when I press media button for long press?

I tried :

```
if (isOrderedBroadcast()) { abortBroadcast(); }
```

but I got bad result, no response for power button,nor one click media button,neither double click media button.

Any idea please ?